# Message boxes (VBA): how can I include/use them in my Excel Macros?

Tags: debugging, excel, logic, vba

I'm teaching myself (read hacking) through some old Excel Macros that are quite long. However, as I change quite a few lines I want to be sure that I know when and where my new and re-hashed elements are occuring - or not. So my question/s is:

- How do I insert a simple message box function that will pop up when a loop/procedure/event has finished?
- Add text to it explaining what happened (hard coded ofcourse)?
- Also, include an "OK button" that makes it start the next procedure?

The breakpoint process may be the most effective way of doing this, but I would like to use the message box approach so that I can show my colleagues what is happening. Also it would be something that I'd like to incorporate into future projects.

Many thanks for any examples, links or helpful hints.
Michael.

Comment: [Julian's Excel Macro (VBA) Tips for Beginners](http://www.angelfire.com/biz7/julian_s/julian/julians_macros.htm) [MessageBox VBA in Excel](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Use_messageboxes_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/415.html)

Comment: You should find intellisense, the F1 key and the Object Browser (F2) useful.

Comment: Yep I agree. I was searching thorugh there while posting this comment. But I find SO a better place to get examples of how things are used, and possible alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
MsgBox ("message here")
```

And if you want to go to the code so that you can debug from there on use CTRL + BREAK

Comment: Should be: `MsgBox "message here"` - i.e. no parentheses unless you are using `Call`

Comment: or unless you're adding yes/no buttons and want to do something with the answer